# Is there a way to do letterSpacing for TextInput in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I've been trying to give `<TextInput>` a letterSpacing style but it seems it only works for `<Text>`. Is there a way in React Native to increase the space between characters in TextInput?

This increases the space between characters

```
<Text style={{'letterSpacing': 5}}>Some Text</Text>
```

This won't work

```
<TextInput style={{'letterSpacing': 5}} />
```

Comment: Add some of your code to show what you have tried.

Comment: No I don't believe there is a character padding type attribute; however, you could write a short function to be called `onChangeText` that could add additional spaces when necessary

Comment: letterSpacing don't show in the emulator, check your app in the device. it will be working.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a hack - nevertheless, it works:

```
<TextInput letterSpacing={5} ... />
```

I have [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67511096/why-do-style-props-work-as-component-props-in-react-natives-view) on SO why style keys also work as props on components, still no answer.
Do not consider this solution permanent, this is obviously not the intended way to style components in RN.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution, maybe not the better.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/jwm6k66c/2190/)

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        value: '',
    };
    this.onChangeText = this.onChangeText.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeText(e) {
    const val = e.target.value.replace(/ /g, '').split('');
    const spaced = val.join(' ');
    this.setState({
        value: spaced,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <div style={{flexDirection: 'column'}}>
        <div>Type Text</div>
        <input
          type='text'
          onChange={this.onChangeText}
          value={this.state.value}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: He said react native and you gave react for web

Comment: The solution changes the value, and thus the functionality...

Answer (score 1):

**You should give letterSpacing inside inputStyle prop.**

*Example:*

```
<TextInput inputStyle={{ letterSpacing: 20 }}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this component
https://github.com/wix/react-native-ui-lib#masked-input
it allows you to render custom masked input in any way you want it, without affecting the actual value of the input.

Answer (score 0):

just put text inside textInput and style it like below

```js
<TextInput 
  placeholder={'1  2      3     4     5     6'}
  style={textInputViewStyle}
  onChangeText={setCode}
  maxLength={6}
>
  <Text style={{ letterSpacing: 19 }}>{code}</Text>
</TextInput>
```